# Flash CS5: addChild and then leave frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What happens when you add a MovieClip to the stage using addChild and then gotoAndStop to a different frame? Is the MovieClip automatically removed? Will it be there when you go back to the same frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will not be removed until you use `removeChild` [and you set all its references to `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832787/is-removechild-enough-to-completely-remove-a-movieclip-from-flash-player-memory). What is happening is, the new frame will overlap the old frame.

Comment: Regarding Lotus's edit, `removeChild()` is perfectly sufficient if all you need to do is take the object off the stage.

Comment: @Lotus and shanethehat : Thanks.